# Can I uplaod a custom font to Big Commerce?

Tags: e-commerce, bigcommerce, custom-font

I want to be able to show our customers a preview of their monogram before they buy, so I need to be able to use a few very specific fonts. I understand how to edit the styling and html but I'm not sure if there is a way to upload something like a font file. Is this possible in Big Commerce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sure can. You would upload it just like any other file, so you have a few options.

1. You could upload it to the **/content/** folder via webdav. You would
   then reference it as yourdomain.com/content/fontfile.extension
2. You could upload it within your **/template/Styles/** folder (usually in
   a sub folder called **/fonts/**). This way, it will be uploaded to the
   CDN (if you've been transitioned to the CDN) which could mean faster
   load times. To reference it this way, you'd use
   %%ASSET_Styles/fonts/fontfile.extension%%

I hope that helps! We also have a great article on connecting via webdav at https://support.bigcommerce.com/questions/1513 and some design resources specific to templates at https://developer.bigcommerce.com/themes/